# Are there multiple equivalent ways of writing an eigenstate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

So my problem here is that I'm confused about how to solve for the eigenstates corresponding to certain eigenvalues.

For my problem I have the Hamiltonian $$ H=E_0 \begin{pmatrix} 
3 & 5i \\
-5i & 3 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
 $$
which yields the eigenvalues $E_1=8E_0$ and $E_2=-2E_0$

Now I plug these eigenvalues back into the eigenvalue equation for the problem $(H-E_nI) |E_n\rangle = 0 $ which gives 
\begin{align}
 a_n(3E_0-E_n)+b_n(5iE_0)&=0 \tag{1}\\
-a_n(5iE_0)+b_n(3E_0-E_n)&=0 
\tag{2}
\end{align}
where I've represented $|E_n\rangle$ as $|E_n\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
a_n \\
b_n \\
\end{pmatrix}\, .$
I use equation (2) and arrive at 
$$ a_n=-ib_n \frac{(3E_0-E_n)}{5E_0} \qquad a_1=ib_1 \tag{3} 
$$ 
Now here is where my confusion comes in. I can either plug $a_1$ into the normalization condition $$ |a_1|^2 + |b_1|^2=1  $$ as follows
$$ 
|ib_1|^2+|b_1|^2 = 1 \qquad |b_1|^2 = \frac{1}{2} \qquad\Rightarrow \qquad 
a_1 = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}
$$ and $$ |E_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
i \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$  or I can rearrange equation (3) as $$ b_1=-ia_1 $$ and plug $b_1$ into the normalization condition to get 
$$ |a_1|^2=\frac{1}{2} \qquad b_1=-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} 
$$ 
which gives 
$$ |E_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-i \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

So are these eigenstates equivalent or did I make a mistake somewhere? Is there a particular variable ($a_1$ or $b_1$ in this case)  that we're supposed to substitute into the normalization condition first?

Comment: They differ just by a phase factor, notice that the second is $-i$ times the first one.

Comment: But is there a preference for choosing one over the other? My professor's solution to this problem gave the second one.

Comment: @Elvis There is generally no preference, especially not in a problem like this. For some classes of problems there are [phase conventions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114104/what-are-phase-conventions-in-angular-momentum-and-rotation-calculations) but in those cases you'll be told what they are.

Comment: Note that a *ket* is not identical to a *state* - a state is a *ray* in Hilbert space where the kets $e^{i\phi}|\psi\rangle$ belong to the same ray.

Answer (score 2):

If $\vert \psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat \Lambda$, then so is $\alpha\vert\psi\rangle$ for any complex $\alpha$ since
$$
\hat \Lambda \alpha \vert\psi\rangle = \alpha \hat \Lambda\vert\psi\rangle = \alpha \lambda \vert\psi\rangle = \lambda (\alpha\vert\psi\rangle)\, .
$$

Normalization pins down the $\alpha$’s to be of the form $e^{i\varphi}$, but you cannot do better than this, i.e. if $\vert \psi\rangle$ is a normalized eigenvector, then $e^{i\varphi}\vert\psi\rangle$ is an equally valid normalized eigenvector.

Physical quantities such as average values of the type $\langle \psi\vert \hat{\cal O}\vert\psi\rangle$ do not depend on the $e^{i\varphi}$ phase, so how you choose this *overall* factor is unimportant.

In your case, your two eigenvectors differ by an overall factor of $-i$, which is precisely of the form $e^{i\varphi}$.  You can work out $\varphi$ by yourself.

Comment: To be sure, it's not that $e^{i\phi}|\psi\rangle$ is an *equally valid state*, it's that $e^{i\phi}|\psi\rangle$ belong to the same ray, i.e., the same *state*.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Nice observation.  I changed “eigenstate” to “eigenvector” to accommodate your comment.